# Problem while trying to flip the sprite of an enemy when moving in a different direction using ASTAR pathfinding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that should flip the sprite left or right depending on the direction of the path it is taking but when I save the script I get the following error, "Cannot modify the return value of "AIBase.desiredVelocity" because it is not a variable".

I apologise if this is a novel issue, I'm quite new to c# and unity.

The aforementioned script is below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Pathfinding;

public class EnemyGFX : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AIPath aiPath;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(aiPath.desiredVelocity.x >= 0.01f)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1f, 1f, 1f);
        }  
        else if (aiPath.desiredVelocity.x = -0.01f)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Under normal circumstances, using the assignment operator (=) in an if statement is inadvisable but wouldn't throw this kind of error. But because Vector3 is a struct (a value type), assigning to its members will throw this error. In any case, as mentioned elsewhere you just need to fix your typo and use the correct comparison operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "else if" line, you're using the assignment operator ("=") where you probably meant to use the less-than-or-equal-to comparison operator ("<=").

The assignment operator sets the value on the left to the value on the right, like you do to set the scales.

The comparison operator returns a boolean value that the if-statement can evaluate.

That's why the error message says that you're trying to modify the desiredVelocity value.